# excel and vba - arrays, variables, and range - changing on the fly

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variables

thank all of you that helped me!  i got it going with YOUR help!  **
:)

I am a 'old school' basic and vb programmer.  i am trying to help a friend with an excel vba app. It concerns an array.  i have NO idea, even after hours of research, on how to do this.

all I see is stuff like:  Range("A1:B10")

I have read some things on here that are CLOSE...but NOT exactly what I am trying to do.

question:  the a1 and b10 will change all the time.  one time it could be s5 and z99, next time, it could be b1 and q55.

I have tried things such as:

```
a="a1:b10":range=(b) = FAIL
a=chr(34)+chr(65)+"1:"+chr(66)+"10"+chr(34):range=(a) = FAIL
range(chr(34)+chr(65)+"1:"+chr(66)+"10"+chr(34)) = FAIL
r="a1":c="e5":range=(r,c) = FAIL
```

how can I assign a vari to the rows and columns so that it becomes:

```
r="a1":c="e5"
.
.
call get_array
.
.
public sub get_array
array=range=(r,c)
```

i am aware that the varis will have to be global, just not sure what 'type'.

I am at a loss as to how to set a sub up so that the rows and columns can be changed 'on the fly'

I will ALWAYS know the following (and they will NOT be 'fixed'):
the start row
the end row
the start column
the end column

The purpose is to copy that 'selection' into an array to be able to add/delete rows as needed. ANY help would be appreciated and i know for yall, even the 'so-so' people at vba probably know this answer.

Also, as a curious question, what if a cell had data AND a formula 'on it', how does this get copied/handled?  copy data, forget formula?  copy formula, forget data?  copy both?  blue screen of death?  ;)

forgive me for being a dummy!
thanks!
:)

Comment: if you have `r="a1":c="e5"`, try `array=Range(r & ":" & c)`. It will give you the same as `array=Range("A1:E5")`

Comment: a cell has a few properties, one being `.formulaR1C1` which will get the cells formula, (seen in the formula bar) and `.value` which will get the displayed value of the cell. (result of formula, if present). when a cell, or range vof cells, is copied, - `Range("A1").copy ` - and pasted, it's the formulas that goes with the cell, and the value may change if, for example, the cell is pasted to a different worksheets where the values in the cells used in the formula are different. if you want the values to be pasted, not the formula, u'd use `.pastespecial(xlPasteValues)`

Comment: `array = Range(Cells(startrow,startcol), Cells(endrow,endcol))`

Answer (score 0):

If you get cell contents, they always come back as a `Variant`. And things turn out much cleaner if you use parameters instead of global variables:

```
Function GetArray(CellRef1 As String, CellRef2 As String) As Variant()
    GetArray = Range(Range(CellRef1), Range(CellRef2)).Value
End Function
```

You'd use it like this:

```
Dim v() As Variant
v = GetArray("A1", "E5")
```

Then `v()` would contain the cell *values.* To get the formulas you need to modify the function a bit:

```
Function GetArrayF(CellRef1 As String, CellRef2 As String) As Variant()
    GetArrayF = Range(Range(CellRef1), Range(CellRef2)).Formula
End Function
```

Comment: if i could give ya a hug i would!  ;)  you got exactly what i was after!  thanks VERY much!  :)